# Create tree list from directories in cakephp 2.x

Tags: php, cakephp

i creating file manager in cakephp 2.x, i need to showing  tree list of '/uploads/' directory and sub-directories.
i have the below code in classic PHP

```
//show recursive directory tree
function print_tree($dir = '.') {
    global $root_path;
  echo '<ul class="dirlist">';
  $d = opendir($dir);
  while($f = readdir($d)) {
    if(strpos($f, '.') === 0) continue;
    $ff = $dir . '/' . $f;
    if(is_dir($ff)) {
      echo '<li><a href="' . $root_path . '/' . $ff . '/" onclick="load(\'mfm.php?viewdir=' . $ff . '\',\'view-files\'); return false;">' . $f . '</a>';
            print_tree($ff);
      echo '</li>';
        }
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
```

but i need cakephp version of the top code

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes i used Folder class  but in folder class:  `$dir = new Folder(APP_DIR.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'uploads'.DS); and $files = $dir->find('.*\.*');` but this structure just return files in the folder

Comment: Well, I am facing the same problem :-) How to display folders, not just files?